# I need a step-by-step guide to navigating directories in Terminal

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, android

I am a Linux/Ubuntu Noob and I have Saucy Salamander. Lately I installed the Android tablet emulator for Ubuntu using VirtualBox from the software center. I followed all the steps listed [here](http://androvm.org/blog/blog/2012/11/14/androvm-configuration-tutorial/) but when I got down to the section where it says 
"AndroVMplayer

The AndroVMplayer is a software used to display the VM content and manage its events. It won’t work if the VM is not running !
Open a command line interpreter, get to the AndroVMplayer directory, and type :
AndroVMplayer [width] [height] [density]"

I have no clue how to navigate directories. Every place I go, it seems they expect people to just know this. I would like a step-by-step guide explaining each step to navigating to that particular directory. Somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

How to navigate to a directory in the terminal using the graphic user interface:

1. Open the file manager for your version of Ubuntu: Files, Nautilus or whatever file manager you are using and browse to the parent directory (up one folder) of the directory you want to navigate to in the terminal.
2. Drag the directory's icon into the terminal. The path to that directory will automatically autocomplete in the terminal.

Some simple terminal navigation commands:

- `cd new-directory` change directory to a directory in the current directory called new-directory
- `cd ~` change directory to user's home directory
- `cd ..` move up one folder
- `cd -` quickly get back
- `ls`  ⠀list directory contents
- `ls -d -- */` list child directories (down one folder) of the current directory